# Suma de Horas y minutos MySQL en dos campos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con un programa en `PHP` con conexion a base de datos `MySQL` todo me ha salido bien excepto en el apartado de obtener el total de horas de entre dos columnas de nombre Entrada y Salida.

El programa captura la hora de entrada y salida de los empleados, ahora lo que quiero es que si en la hora de salida se tarda mas de `20 min` en salir ya cumple un hora extra sin salario, osease que su hora de entrada era a las `9pm` y sale a las `4pm suman` `7Hrs` pero si se tarda y registra `4:20pm` ya cuenta como una hora mas, es decir, `8Hrs` en total.

Para obtener la suma de las dos columnas de `Hora_entrada` y `Hora_salida`
hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT HOUR(SUM(TIMEDIFF(Hora_entrada, Hora_salida))) FROM control;
```

Eso me de la suma total de horas trabajadas, pero no me suma los minutos.

¿En que parte debo mejorar mi consulta para que me sume los minutos junto con las horas de las 2 columnas?

Comment: que formato tienen la columnas datetime, time???

Comment: es que estas sacando las horas con la funcion HOUR.. o sea que suma los minutos, pero no los muestras...

Comment: tienen tim, en lo que investique me decia que con eso, pero por eso pregunto por aqui jejej :V para ver como solucionarlo jejeje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es esto:

```
SELECT  SUM( 
        HOUR(TIMEDIFF(Hora_entrada, Hora_salida)) + 
        CASE WHEN MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(Hora_entrada, Hora_salida)) % 60 > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    FROM control;
```

Es decir la suma de:

1. Diferencia en horas entre `Hora_entrada`, `Hora_salida`
2. Si la resto de dividir la diferencia en minutos por 60 (1 hora) es mayor a 20 sumo 1 hora

Comment: wow si me late, ahora lo verifico va :)

Comment: Hola he usado tu comando pero pero aun asi me sigue marcando 7 hrs en vez de 8

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tal como lo escribí, solo suma 1 hora más si hay al menos 21 minutos adicionales. Cualquier cosa copia Hora_entrada y Hora_salida en un comentario así puedo analizarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Lo mejor en estos casos que ya queremos hacer algo especial es pasarlo a segundos. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT ceil((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Hora_salida) - 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Hora_entrada))/3600) from control;
```

Pasas a segundos **UNIX_TIMESTAMP** ambos campos, lo restas y lo divides entre 3600 para que te de un número decimal. Luego sólo tienes que redondear hacia arriba con la función **ceil**.

Comment: Ok ahora verfico :)

Comment: Hola, si guarde la entrada a las `22:31:11.000000` y salida a las `23:10:32.000000` al usar tu consulta el resultado es 1 eso que significa, es que no me quedo claro. Perdon

Answer (score 1):

te hace falta la segunda parte de la consulta:

```
MINUTE(SUM(TIMEDIFF(Hora_entrada, Hora_salida)))
```

debe quedar algo como puedes verificarlo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
HOUR(SUM(TIMEDIFF(Hora_entrada, Hora_salida))), ':',
MINUTE(SUM(TIMEDIFF(Hora_entrada, Hora_salida)))) FROM control;
```

Comment: Aqui se suma las horas y luego los minutos ?

Comment: si de forma independiente y al final los concatenas.

Comment: Oh ya okey, lo verificare igual :)

Comment: lo que no he probado es que pasa si la suma de minutos es mayor a minutos 59:59 .

Comment: :0 ok ntp, checare de todo modos, pero agradeceria si lo verificaras :)

Comment: @SantiagoHuh yo no tengo la base de datos joven usted la tiene.

Comment: jejejeje si es cierto perdon :)

Answer (score 1):

Estas anexando funciones de más para obtener el tiempo transcurrido, te pongo un ejemplo para que te guies como podrías implementarlo.

*Obtengo la fecha y hora de la hora de ejecución del **select** y anexo suponiendo la fecha de entrada, en **now()** y la fecha por default que coloque puedes anexar la hora de entrada y salida.*

```
SELECT TIME(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),'2017-07-17 08:30:00.00'));
```

Resultado:

```
05:13:06
```

Ya si lo que quieres es obetener un valor es especifico usa `TIME_FORMAT()`.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIME(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),'2017-07-17 08:30:00.00')),'%H:%i');
```

Resultado:

```
 05:16
```

Comment: las dos fechas estan en la base de datos tanto la de entrada como salida; el desea calcula el total de horas y minutos de esas dos columnas, no tiene nada que ver con respecto a la hora de ejecucion ni el formato.

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente a lo que te refieres, pero creo que ahí claramente indique de reemplaze now() y la fecha por default que anexe por la hora de entrada y salida.

Comment: @DesarrolladorAndroidJr. necesito tu ayduda en mi ultima pregunta :C

Comment: Podrías indicarme cual es la pregunta, para ver en que te puedo ayudar?? @IvanMoreFlores

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88003/direccionar-mi-boton-a-google-maps-en-android