# Direccionar mi boton a google maps en Android

Tags: android

Hola vengo realizando una APP, que basicamente es llenada mediante una WebService, donde obtengo toda la informacion en ella su `latitud` y `longitud` en este ejemplo de un colegio x, en mi detalle e puesto un boton de mapàs es decir que si le da click te direcciona al aplicativo que biene por defecto en android o ya sea al maps de chrome, basicamnte en mi aplicativo ya tengo la latitud y longitud:

```
public String getLatitud() {
        return latitud;
    }

    public String getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }
```

Bueno este es la parte de la escucha del boton

```
// Setear escucha para el fab
mapsButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Iniciar actividad de de Localizacion
                    }
                }
        );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo completo:**

```
    public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

        /**
         * Etiqueta de depuración
         */
        private static final String TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        /*
        Instancias de Views
         */
        private ImageView cabecera;
        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView institucion;
        private TextView codigo_plaza;
        private TextView modalidad;
        private TextView especialidad;
        private TextView nivel;
        private TextView tipo_vacante;
        private TextView jornada;
        private TextView motivo;
        private TextView estado;
        private ImageButton editButton;
        private String extra;
        private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public DetailFragment() {
    }

    public static DetailFragment createInstance(String idMeta) {
        DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constantes.EXTRA_ID, idMeta);
        detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return detailFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);


        // Obtención de views
        cabecera = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cabecera);
        titulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        institucion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.institucion);
        codigo_plaza = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo_plaza);
        modalidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.modalidad);
        especialidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
        nivel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
        tipo_vacante = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tipo_vacante);
        jornada = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jornada);
        motivo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.motivo);
        estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
        editButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        // Obtener extra del intent de envío
        extra = getArguments().getString(Constantes.EXTRA_ID);

        // Setear escucha para el fab
mapsButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Iniciar actividad de de Localizacion
                    }
                }
        );

        // Cargar datos desde el web service
        cargarDatos();

        return v;
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene los datos desde el servidor
     */
    public void cargarDatos() {

        // Añadir parámetro a la URL del web service
        String newURL = Constantes.GET_BY_ID + "?plazaID=" + extra;

        // Realizar petición GET_BY_ID
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
                new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET,
                        newURL,
                        null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                // Procesar respuesta Json
                                procesarRespuesta(response);
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Procesa cada uno de los estados posibles de la
     * respuesta enviada desde el servidor
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            // Obtener atributo "mensaje"
            String mensaje = response.getString("estado");

            switch (mensaje) {
                case "1":
                    // Obtener objeto "meta"
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("meta");

                    //Parsear objeto 
                    Plaza plaza = gson.fromJson(object.toString(), Plaza.class);

                    // Asignar color del fondo
                    switch (plaza.getEstado()) {
                        case "0":
                            cabecera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ocupadoColor));
                            estado.setText("OCUPADO");
                            titulo.setText("OCUPADO");
                            break;
                        case "1":
                            cabecera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vacanteColor));
                            estado.setText("VACANTE");
                            titulo.setText("VACANTE");
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            cabecera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.reservadolColor));
                            estado.setText("RESERVADO");
                            titulo.setText("RESERVADO");
                            break;
                    }
                    // Seteando valores en los views

                    institucion.setText(plaza.getIe());
                    codigo_plaza.setText(plaza.getCodigoPlaza());
                    modalidad.setText(plaza.getModalidad());
                    especialidad.setText(plaza.getEspecialidad());
                    nivel.setText(plaza.getNivel());
                    tipo_vacante.setText(plaza.getTipoVacante());
                    jornada.setText(plaza.getJornada()+" HORAS");
                    motivo.setText(plaza.getMotivoVacante());
                    //estado.setText(plaza.getEstado());

                    break;

                case "2":
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case "3":
                    String mensaje3 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para abrir el google maps que viene por defecto en los móviles tendrías que hacer uso de **Intent**.

En el Intent anexo como parametro

> ACTION_VIEW (Activity Action: Display the data to the user.)

En el uri lo que agregamos fue la acción que queremos que se ejecute en este caso

> geo:

Seguido de los *parametros* que nos solicita, para que se muestre la ubicación y el texto que enviaremos a **google maps**

```
if(instancia.getLatitud()==null && instancia.getLongitud())
{   //suponiendo que tienes un metodo que lanza un mensaje
    mostrarAlerta("No se puede realizar la busqueda en mapa");
}else{
    String labelLocation = "Titulo: Si se quiere anexar algo de texto aquí";
    String uri = "geo:<" + getLatitud()+ ">,<" + getLongitud()+ ">?q=<" + getLatitud()+ ">,<" + getLongitud()+ ">(" + labelLocation + ")";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Como Resultado te debe de mostrar algo como esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Intent(String action, Uri uri)
>
> Create an intent with a given action and for a given data url.

Te dejo el link de la documentación de como usar Intent
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Muchas gracias e puesto el codigo completo porfa ayudame que ise mal :c

Comment: Muéstrame como anexaste el codigo

Comment: ayudame @Desarrollador Android Jr https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90452/searchview-en-actionbar-segundo-error-se-a-detenido-la-aplicaci%c3%b3n