# SearchView en ActionBar [Se ha detenido la aplicación]

Tags: android

Cuando ejecuto mi app me devuelve errores que la verdad no se si son de programación o de librerías, espero me puedan ayudar.

La lista lo lleno mediante una `WEBSERVICE`

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las lineas que me marcan error son las siguientes :

```
//linea 164 y su complemento
    for (Plaza model : models) {
        final String text = model.getCodigoPlaza().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filPlazaList.add(model);
        }
    }

//linea 150 y su complemento
final List<Plaza> filteredModelList = filter(plazas, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
```

> **La verdad que no tengo idea de que pueda ser el error **

Dejo el código completo quizás sea me este equivocando en algún lado:

**Código de mi MainActivity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creación del fragmento principal
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment(), "MainFragment")
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constantes.CODIGO_DETALLE || requestCode == 3) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK || resultCode == 203) {
                MainFragment fragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                        findFragmentByTag("MainFragment");
                fragment.cargarAdaptador();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Código de mi MainFragment :**

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    /*
    Etiqueta de depuracion
     */
    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
    Adaptador del recycler view
     */
    private MetaAdapter adapter;

    /*
    Instancia global del recycler view
     */
    private RecyclerView lista;

    /*
    instancia global del administrador
     */
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager;

    /*
    Instancia global del FAB
     */

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

     /*
    Instancia global para el refresh
     */
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private List<Plaza> plazas;



    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Habilitar al fragmento para contribuir en la action bar
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        lista = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
        lista.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        lista.setLayoutManager(lManager);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_main);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setDistanceToTriggerSync(80);// in dips
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                cargarAdaptador();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Cargar datos en el adaptador
        cargarAdaptador();

        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_form, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        //
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean  onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                        adapter.setFilter(plazas);
                        return true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<Plaza> filteredModelList = filter(plazas, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private List<Plaza> filter(List<Plaza> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        //
        final List<Plaza> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Plaza model : models) {
            final String text = model.getCodigoPlaza().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
    return filteredModelList;

    }





    /**
     * Carga el adaptador con las metas obtenidas
     * en la respuesta
     */
    public void cargarAdaptador() {
        // Petición GET
        VolleySingleton.
                getInstance(getActivity()).
                addToRequestQueue(
                        new JsonObjectRequest(
                                Request.Method.GET,
                                Constantes.GET,
                                null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        // Procesar la respuesta Json
                                        procesarRespuesta(response);
                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.toString());
                                    }
                                }

                        )
                );
    }

    /**
     * Interpreta los resultados de la respuesta y así
     * realizar las operaciones correspondientes
     *
     * @param response Objeto Json con la respuesta
     */
    private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            // Obtener atributo "estado"
            String estado = response.getString("estado");

            switch (estado) {
                case "1": // EXITO
                    // Obtener array "metas" Json
                    JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");
                    // Parsear con Gson
                    Plaza[] plazas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Plaza[].class);
                    // Inicializar adaptador
                    adapter = new MetaAdapter(Arrays.asList(plazas), getActivity());
                    // Setear adaptador a la lista
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case "2": // FALLIDO
                    String mensaje2 = response.getString("mensaje");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            mensaje2,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

**Código de mi MetaAdapter :**

```
public class extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Plaza> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Plaza> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        switch(items.get(i).getEstado())
        {
            case "0":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("OCUPADO");
                break;
            case "1":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("VACANTE");
                break;
            case "2":
                viewHolder.estado.setText("RESERVADO");
                break;
            default:
                viewHolder.estado.setText("ERROR");
        }
        viewHolder.nivel.setText(items.get(i).getNivel());
        //viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());
        viewHolder.colegio.setText(items.get(i).getIe());
        viewHolder.especialidad.setText(items.get(i).getEspecialidad());
        viewHolder.codigo.setText(items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza());
    }


    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getPlazaID());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView nivel;
        public TextView estado;
        public TextView colegio;
        public TextView especialidad;
        public TextView codigo;
        public ItemClickListener listener;


        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            nivel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
            estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
            colegio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.colegio);
            especialidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
            codigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<Plaza> plazas){
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.addAll(plazas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

**Imagen antes de realizar una búsqueda, luego la app se cierra :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo sino me equivoco es que la variable plazas es nula en algún momento de tu ejecución, ya que  la defines como `private List<Plaza> plazas;` en tu MainFragment y puede darse el caso que al llamar a `filter(plazas, newText);` no tenga valor asignado, por lo que te dará el error de que estás iterando sobre un objeto nulo.

Te aconsejo que declares tu variable plazas como un array vacío, así evitarás este problema :

```
private List<Plaza> plazas = new ArrayList<Plaza> ();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, por tu rapida respuesta, doy por cerrada esta pregunta, espero un voto positivo, por otro lado no hace la busqueda :c, es decir no muestra resultados